# CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application in Eclipse CDT

Tags: windows, shell, eclipse-cdt, external-tools

I'm using Eclipse CDT in Windows. I have imported a project which needs to be run by a `.sh` file.

I built the project first, and as you can see in the picture linked below, the file `tcas.exe` is in the `Debug` folder.

I have a script file named `runall.sh` which I want to run to pass arguments with values. It's like this:

```
echo ">>>>>>>>running test 1"
../source/tcas.exe  958 1 1 2597  574 4253 0  399  400 0 0 1     > ../outputs/t1
```

[inside project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LvX9.png)

To run the `runall.sh`, I've created an external tool like this:

```
Location: ${workspace_loc:/tcas/tcas/scripts/runall.sh}
Working Directory: empty
Arguments:  Cur_Vertical_Sep
            High_Confidence
            Two_of_Three_Reports_Valid
            Own_Tracked_Alt
            Own_Tracked_Alt_Rate
            Other_Tracked_Alt
            Alt_Layer_Value
            Up_Separation
            Down_Separation
            Other_RAC
```

When I run the external tool, it gives me the following error message:

> Exception occurred executing command line.
>   Cannot run program "H:\Java Workplace\tcas\tcas\scripts\runall.sh":
>   CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application"

What is the cause of this error? What is necessary to successfully run this script?

how can I use cygwin to make runall.sh executable ?

Comment: Since it's not an executable which it probably expects, you might try executing `cmd` and giving the script to it to run

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain more about how should I do that ? I haven't worked much with cmd .